# Unable to import recently moved project into Eclipse

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

My project was created and worked on under the Download directory but then I moved it to C: root directory.
Now when I open Eclipse and do File > Open Projects from File System it doesn't import the project at all. There is no error, it just doesn't show anything.

I am sure Eclipse is pointing to the new workspace.
Could it be that the project itself has some sort of reference to the old directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can try **File > Import > General > Existing Projects into Workspace** instead.